# Why does my model render shady / half-black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I imported a Wavefront model (OBJ + MTL) and tried to render it using Cycles. Unfortunately, model renders shady / half-black. It seems that only one wheel looks as expected. I can't figure out what causes this behavior.

[image]

I would appreciate any help!

P.S. Source Blend file: https://nofile.io/f/q1ArSbeAva0/Shady_Car.7z

Comment: Hard to see the geometry from just the render. Do the other tires have materials properly assigned? Also check that face normals point outwards with CTRL-N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **custom split normals data** on your model, You should to delete it, then blender will recalculate normals properly.

1. Removing custom norlals in **Geometry data** section:

[image]

2. Then select all faces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: It's a little bit offtopic, but still: what's the equivalent of *custom split normals data* in 3Ds Max?